# How to parse XSD1.1 features, precisely <xs:assert> tag?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd, xsd-1.1

I have been using XSOM parser (xsom-20140925.jar) for parsing XSD 1.0 and able to achieve parsing all xs:elements and restrictions (like pattern, minOccurs etc..).

Lately our XSD1.0 been upgraded to version XSD1.1, where new assert tag been included.
My XSOM parser fails to identify this assert tag and throws the following exception.

**Could not parse the inputstream: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected `<xsd:assert>` appears at line.
java.lang.NullPointerException**

Basically my need is to automate all restrictions in XSD to JavaScript Functions, so that client side UI can be validated.

I have done Googling and understand that Xerces-j can only validate an XML against XSD1.1.

But my requirement is to parse assert values and convert in to JavaScript functions.

Consider the following assert example: Here I need to parse the value between double quotes"", and arrive an JavaScript function according to the conditions.

```
xsd:assert test="(exists(companyName) and companyTier='TierOne')"
```

Is there a way to achieve the above requirement?
Any help or suggestions would help me a lot.

..............................................................................

Thanks for your answer.
By turning off the sax validaiton would allow me to parse the assert tag value.
But my requirement is to convert those assert values(show below) which is XSD1.1 feature in to a Java Regular expression or any expression which could be evaluated 
and also I should have the proper links i.e to which element this assert tag pertains to.

I understand xercesImpl-xsd11-2.12-beta has Xpath2.0 processor which can be used.
But I'm not able to parse the XSD in to XSModel with the assert tag present.

XSD FILE USED:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Example" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Example">
    <element name="Node" type="tns:NodeType"></element>
    <complexType name="NodeType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Node" type="tns:NodeType"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            </element>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="partnumber">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="string">
                    <pattern value="[A-Z0-9_\-]+"></pattern>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
        <assert test="starts-with(@partnumber,../@partnumber)"/>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Java Code to parse:

System.setProperty(DOMImplementationRegistry.PROPERTY, "org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMXSImplementationSourceImpl");

```
    DOMImplementationRegistry registry;
    XSNamedMap xsMap;
    try {
        registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();

        XSImplementationImpl impl = (XSImplementationImpl) registry.getDOMImplementation("XS-Loader");
        XSLoader schemaLoader = impl.createXSLoader(null);
        XSModel model = schemaLoader.loadURI("testxsdassert.xsd");
        }
```

On executing the following error is shown in console:
[Error] testxsdassert.xsd:17:65: s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'NodeType' is invalid.  Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Any leads or suggestion would help me.

Thanks.

................................................................................

Sorry for not being clear on the requirement. Let me try it again.

1. Existing XSOM parser(see below code) will parse any XSD and retrieve all restriction like MINLENGTH, MAXLENGTH, PATTERN, ENUMERATION against any element present in XSD.
   This parser intention is to just parse these values and store against its element name. 
   For the below example(parser.xsd) this structure is derived-> {allowedMonths,["JAN","FEB"]}

After parsing i would convert the parsed structure {allowedMonths,["JAN","FEB"]} in to JavaScript function, where this function is called in UI validation to check the user entered value is accordance to XSD dynamically.

This was working fine till now. This solution was to automate such that on any new additions in XSD this parser shall take care the JS code generation.

```
**Parser.xsd**
    <xsd: simpleType name="allowedMonths">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="JAN"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="FEB"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
 **Parser.java**
            XSOMParser parser;
            parser.parse(xml);
            XSSchemaSet schemaSet = null;
                try {
                    schemaSet = parser.getResult();
                } catch (SAXException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Could not parse: " + ex);
                }
                Iterator <XSElementDecl> itre = schemaSet.iterateElementDecls();
                 while(itre.hasNext()) {
                    XSElementDecl xse = (XSElementDecl) itre.next();
                    hmReturned.put(xse.getName(), hm);
                    XSComplexType xscomp = xse.getType().asComplexType();
                    if (xscomp != null) {
                        XSContentType xscont = xscomp.getContentType();
                        XSParticle particle = xscont.asParticle();
                        getElementsRecursively(hm,  particle);
                    }
                } 

                private void getElementsRecursively(HashMap<String, Object> hm, XSParticle xsp) {

                 if(xsp != null){
                     XSTerm term = xsp.getTerm();
                     if(term.isElementDecl()) {
                         XSComplexType xscmp =  (term.asElementDecl()).getType().asComplexType();
                         //---
                         if (xscmp == null){
                             MappingXSDJSElement mapElementObj = new MappingXSDJSElement();
                             //public List<String> enumeration = new ArrayList<String>();
                             if(xsp.getTerm().asElementDecl().getType().asSimpleType() != null)
                             {
                                 if(xsp.getTerm().asElementDecl().getType().asSimpleType().isRestriction())
                                 {
                                     XSRestrictionSimpleType restriction=xsp.getTerm().asElementDecl().getType().asSimpleType().asRestriction();
                                     if(restriction != null){
                                            List<String> enumeration = new ArrayList<String>();
                                            Iterator<? extends XSFacet> i = restriction.getDeclaredFacets().iterator();
                                            while(i.hasNext()){
                                                XSFacet facet = i.next();

                                                if(facet.getName().equals(XSFacet.FACET_MAXLENGTH)){
                                                    mapElementObj.setMaxLength(facet.getValue().value);

                                                }
                                                if(facet.getName().equals(XSFacet.FACET_MINLENGTH)){
                                                    mapElementObj.setMinLength(facet.getValue().value);

                                                }
                                                if(facet.getName().equals(XSFacet.FACET_PATTERN)){
                                                    mapElementObj.setPattern(facet.getValue().value);

                                                }
                                                if(facet.getName().equals(XSFacet.FACET_ENUMERATION)){
                                                    enumeration.add(facet.getValue().value);
                                                    mapElementObj.setEnumeration(enumeration);
                                                   // System.out.println(enumeration.toString());
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }    
                                 }
                             }
                             if(xsp.getMinOccurs().intValue() == 0)
                             {
                                // hm.put(term.asElementDecl().getName(), "|");
                                 mapElementObj.setMinOccurs("0");
                             }
                             else if(xsp.getMinOccurs().intValue() == 1)
                             {
                                // hm.put(term.asElementDecl().getName(), "=");
                                 mapElementObj.setMinOccurs("1");
                             }

                             hm.put(term.asElementDecl().getName(), mapElementObj);

                         } else{
                             XSContentType xscont = xscmp.getContentType();
                             XSParticle particle = xscont.asParticle();
                             HashMap<String, Object> newHm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                             getElementsRecursively(newHm, particle);
                             hm.put(term.asElementDecl().getName(), newHm);
                         }
                         //---
                     } else if(term.isModelGroup()){
                         XSModelGroup model = term.asModelGroup();
                         XSParticle[] parr = model.getChildren();
                         for(XSParticle partemp : parr ){
                           getElementsRecursively(hm, partemp);
                         }
                     }
                 }
            }
```

2. Requirement: Now XSD had been enhanced to include  to have cross field validations. So eventually i had to enhance my parser to capture these assert for each element and arrive JavaScript functions 
   for each element of XSD.
   SO I need to find a way to parse these assert values present in any simple and complex type elements.

Your suggestion of parsing as raw type XML doesn't seem to fit in to my existing XSOM parser. i.e  i was looking for parser API to get values of  tag, so that solution is generic to any XSD.

Any suggestions on this approach would help to solve the issue.

Comment: Your edit hasn't helped to explain your goal.  Your error indicates that you're trying to parse a 1.1 XSD using a 1.0 XSD processor.  Since you say that all you really want is to get at the `xs:assert/@test` value, I [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33151415/290085) that you just parse the XSD as a raw XML file without validation, but you've not explained why that doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Your stated goal has to do with generating JavaScript (?!) from the results of your parsing of `xs:assert` elements, and I suspect there may be a bit of a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on here.   Sorry, but it's too unclear what your real end goal is.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: @kjhughes I had edited again to explain my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the XSD with validation turned off so that you're reading it as a raw XML file, then it won't matter whether it's a 1.0 or 1.1 XSD.

[Set](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html) the [`http://xml.org/sax/features/validation`](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#validation) feature to false:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

try {
    dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    System.err.println("could not set parser feature");
}
```

Comment: I think DocumentBuilderFactory cant be used with XSOM parser.
I tried using SAXParserFactory like this,
SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
saxFactory.setValidating(false);
saxfactory.setfeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);

Then passing the factory while initializing the XSOM Parser

XSOMParser parser = new XSOMParser(saxfactory)

Even by then i'm getting the same SAXException.

Could you please suggest on this?